# How can I make VSC auto-format my TypeScript code on save according to my TSLint rules?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, lint, autosave

Thanks. What are the default formatting rules being used for TypeScript?
I'm working from a template setup with TSLint.

VSC inserts a space before : on variable type declarations.
My TSLint complains that I have a space a before : and I don't want the space there.

```
(snapshot : any) => { ... }
```

My TSLint config (and I) want it to be the following form

```
(snapshot : any) => { ... }
```

How can I make VSC behave on auto-save adhering to my TSLint formatting rules? I've also tried using the Prettier extension, but now have it disabled as I tried to figure out what was going on. Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.